# replace all py files with pyc files in directory

Tags: python, pyc

I want to be able to ship only the `.pyc` files so I achieve lightweight/basic obfuscation in my shipped application.

I tried the command line -

```
python -m compileall -f C:\MOT_Server\olympus-skeleton\dist\olympus_server
```

But all `py` files remain.

I wish that every `py` file will be replaced with `pyc` file, and not that all `pyc` files will be dumped to `__pycache__` folder.

Comment: _But all py files remain_ So remove them?  What's the problem?

Comment: All pyc files in a directory are dumped to a created `__pycache__` folder. I am working on a big project with many packages. so i was wondering if there's a way to use, for instance, `compileall ` in such way that every py file will be replaced with pyc file.

Comment: `compileall` will not remove the py files.  You'll have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get rid of `.py` files yourself, but `find` shall be useful for that:

```
find . -type f -name "*.py" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Note: it will go recursive!

If you are unfamiliar with `find`, remove `-exec ...` part for testing to have all "qualified" files printed out:

```
find . -type f -name "*.py"
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that `find` supports a `-delete` flag so you can use: `find . -type f -name "*.py" -delete`